# Adding remote git link to file header Intellij Idea

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

Here is my header template, but also I want to be able to add git remote link here, cause I know, that IDEA is integrated with GitHub/Bitbucket and stores links somewhere. Something kinda:

```
/**
 * Created by: Anton Shkurenko (${USER})
 * Project: ${PROJECT_NAME}
 * External link: ${REMOTE_URL} // here
 * Date: ${DATE}
 */
```

How to do that?